# Spring test: UnknownServiceException: ConnectionProvider

Tags: spring, hibernate, testing

I have a number of test classes which start spring contexts, each containing hibernate (and EntityManagerFactory).

A custom TestExecutionListener ensures that spring contexts are always marked as dirty, so a context should never be reused.

During subsequent startups of a spring context (not the first startup) I get:

```
org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
```

What can cause this exception? Was a previous spring context not properly closed?

Edit/added: The above exception is actually thrown when trying to start a transaction within a bean, during startup. (`Lifecycle.start()`). So the question is why is there no hibernate SessionFactory available when there should be - and there is for the first spring test context that is created (for the first test class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was caused by leaking of references to the old spring context (in custom code).

Answer (score 0):

The exception is probably caused by trying to create a new session while SessionFactory is closed

Make sure you are not calling transactional methods in non transactional tests.

[test context:](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx)

```
In the TestContext framework, transactions are managed by the TransactionalTestExecutionListener, which is configured through the @TestExecutionListeners annotation by default, even if you do not explicitly declare @TestExecutionListeners on your test class. To enable support for transactions, however, you must provide a PlatformTransactionManager bean in the application context loaded by @ContextConfiguration semantics. In addition, you must declare @Transactional either at the class or method level.
```

[TransactionalTestExecutionListener:](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/TransactionalTestExecutionListener.html)

```
... test methods that are not annotated with either @Transactional (at the class or method level) or @NotTransactional will not be run within a transaction.
```

Comment: Do you mean that @Transactional should be put on all tests that might use the database. Such annotations are already in place in the proper places in beans.

I don't see why the SessionFactory should be closed when the Spring Context is loaded and currently refreshing (starting).

Comment: I'm talking about AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests.

Comment: Thanks. But the test should not be transactional itself. Transactions are started at "deeper" levels, within certain beans. Besides, running my test with TransactionalTestExecutionListener and @Transactional does not change anything.